# How to fill every nth row of a data.frame column with values from another data.frame's column?

Tags: r, dataframe

What I want to do is fill up a dataframe's column with values from a different dataframe's column. However, I only want every nth row to have a value inserted into it

```
temp <- data.frame(value = numeric(312))
temp_2 <- matrix(3:80)
```

How can I insert temp_2's values into every 4th row of temp, so that temp will look like this?

```
head(temp, 12)
   value
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       3
5       0
6       0
7       0
8       4
9       0
10      0
11      0
12      5
```

My thoughts were that using seq() would be a good solution. Perhaps something similar to the code below, but without an error. To restate my goal, I want every sequential value from temp_2, to be put in every 4th row of temp, so that all of temp_2's values will fit in temp. However, this resulted in an "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix" error.

```
temp$value[seq(from = 4, to = 312, by = 4),1] <- temp_2[1:78,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make a little mistake, you try to modify the first column of the first column of your dataframe, you should write either:

```r
temp$value[seq(from = 4, to = 312, by = 4)] <- temp_2[1:78,1]
```

or:

```r
temp[seq(from = 4, to = 312, by = 4),1] <- temp_2[1:78,1]
```

Otherwise, your solution was the good one, just a typo issue ;)

Comment: I see, I chose the first option you gave me, and that worked. I was not expecting my code to be even close to working, but at least give you an idea of what I wanted to do. If I may, can I ask the same question, but using the actual code i'm working on? The code I originally posted was just for duplicating. The actual line of code I am having trouble with is this ```df_3$value[seq(from = 4, to = 312, by = 4)] <- female_ns[seq(from = 3, to = 80, by = 1),2] ``` while this puts the values into every 4th row like i want, it puts a vector of EVERY value from female_ns into each row.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. Did you solve your issue ? If not, you can add your issue to your current question with a little example of your code

Comment: Yes, I got it all figured out. I realized that female_ns was not a data.frame, but a list. A popular stackoverflow question helped me convert it. but strangely enough... typeof() still says female_ns is a list, even though the code ```female_ns <- as.data.frame(female_ns, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE)``` solved my "vector of all values" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using recycling property of R

```
temp$value[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)] <- temp_2[,1]
temp
#    value
#1       0
#2       0
#3       0
#4       3
#5       0
#6       0
#7       0
#8       4
#9       0
#10      0
#11      0
#12      5
#....
```